# MongoTemplate update multiple Document with at once without using saveAll() or loops

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql, mongotemplate

I'm having trouble saving multiple document at once, my need is that while update multiple document it updates only the targeted field:
What i'm trying to do :

```
Update1 ("field Name" , " AB" ) ;
Update2 ("field Name", "ABC");
Query query = mongoTemplate.Aggr(...)

mongoTemplate.multipleUpdate(..,Update1, Update 2);
```

Is there any way possible to do this?

Comment: You can use insertMany functionality in mongodb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i figured out myself by using BulkOperations you can stack multiple Update into bulks and then execute it at the same time!
My code:

```
BulkOperations bulkOperations = mongoTemplate.bulkOps(BulkOperations.BulkMode.UNORDERED, Foo.class);

        List<Foo> fooList = FooRepository.findAllByIdIn(Arrays.asList(id));
        for (Foo foo : fooList) {
            Query query = new Query().addCriteria(new Criteria("...").is(...));
            Update update = new Update().set(..., ...);
            bulkOperations.updateOne(query, update);
        }
        bulkOperations.execute();
```